# POST an mp3 file using CURL

Tags: post, upload, curl, mp3, multipartform-data

I have been searching and trying different configurations for POSTing mp3 files via CURL for a few hours, but none seem to work. The most recent form I have settled on looks like this:

curl -F "file=@multipartEncode.txt;type=audio/mpeg" -A "Mozilla/5.0"
http://65.173.255.180:8000/accounts/user/songs/

This format seems to have everything necessary for sending the multipart encoded mp3 file (I first place the encoded info in multipartEncode.txt) to the server, yet it always fails. I've tried it this way and replaced the @ with <. I know for a fact that the server is working because its fine when I point the action parameter of the html form directly at the server. So that means that I'm missing something in my CURL request....but what could it be???

Answer (score 5):

```
curl -F "file=@myfile.mp3;type=audio/mpeg" -A "Mozilla/5.0" http://65.173.255.180:8000/accounts/user/songs/
```

Comment: Thanks, I greatly appreciate your quick reply. I tried changing the multipartEncode.txt to the extension: .mp3; but it has had no effect...although I feel better knowing I'm very close.